convert multiple terraform blocks to for_each loop
I have multiple blocks that use the databricks_catalog resource
resource "databricks_catalog" "sf_bronze_bc_westeurope_managed_catalog" {
  owner   = "mip-admin-group"
  name    = "sf_bronze"
}
resource "databricks_catalog" "sf_deltasharing_bc_westeurope_managed_catalog" {
  owner = "mip-admin-group"
  name  = "sf_deltasharing"
}

I am trying to convert them to a loop using for_each
resource "databricks_catalog" "this" {
  for_each = var.catalog

  name           = each.key
  owner          = each.value.catalog_owner
}

With variables.tf as follows:
variable "catalog" {
  type = map(object({
    catalog_grants         = optional(map(list(string)))
    catalog_owner          = optional(string)         # Username/groupname/sp application_id of the catalog owner.
    catalog_storage_root   = optional(string)         # Location in cloud storage where data for managed tables will be stored
    catalog_isolation_mode = optional(string, "OPEN") # Whether the catalog is accessible from all workspaces or a specific set of workspaces. Can be ISOLATED or OPEN.
    catalog_comment        = optional(string)         # User-supplied free-form text
    catalog_properties     = optional(map(string))    # Extensible Catalog Tags.
    schema_name            = optional(list(string))   # List of Schema names relative to parent catalog.
    schema_grants          = optional(map(list(string)))
    schema_owner           = optional(string) # Username/groupname/sp application_id of the schema owner.
    schema_comment         = optional(string)
    schema_properties      = optional(map(string))
  }))
  default = {
    sf_bronze = {
      catalog_owner = "mip-admin-group"
    }
    sf_deltasharing= {
      catalog_owner = "mip-admin-group"
    }
  }
}

However terraform plan wants to destroy the existing catalogs and create new catalogs with the same name. The resource name (sf_bronze_bc_westeurope_managed_catalog, sf_deltasharing_bc_westeurope_managed_catalog) is what is missing from the refactored for_each block. How can I add the resource name as a parameter? Is that the reason the new code wants to destroy the catalog? Is the resource name used as the identifier for infrastructure that is in the state?

The short answer, yes. A bit longer answer is that you could use the import block to tell terraform what has moved where.

I already used the terraform databricks expoter (https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databricks/databricks/latest/docs/guides/experimental-exporter) to get the import.sh & .tf files to describe the manually created infra.
Next step is to convert those manual blocks to loops.

What is var.catalog? Can you add that to the question as well?

yes of course. added

Versions of terraform >= 1.7.x have introduced the option of using for_each with the import block. However, variables cannot be used as they are not known before the import, so locals have to be used. In your case, I would try something like the following:
locals {
  catalog = {  
    sf_bronze = {
      catalog_owner = "mip-admin-group"
    }
    sf_deltasharing = {
      catalog_owner = "mip-admin-group"
    }
  }
}

import {
  for_each = local.catalog
  to       = databricks_catalog.this[each.key]
  id       = each.key
}

resource "databricks_catalog" "this" {
  for_each = local.catalog
  name     = each.key
  owner    = each.value.catalog_owner
}

If the import is successful, you can swap the local.catalog with var.catalog and remove the locals and import blocks.

Thanks. Is it possible to change the name of an existing resource for a given catalog? The issue is that the auto-exporter I used (https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databricks/databricks/latest/docs/guides/experimental-exporter) created these long convoluted names. "sf_bronze_bc_westeurope_managed_catalog".
Ideally the resource name would be the same as the catalog name....
These differences in names are the reason why terraform wants to destroy & then create again.

Ah, well, as the documentation says, I guess the names are the only way to import the resource.

terraform state mv can be used to rename from clunky to the same name as the catalog. Then the for_each should work

Yeah, that should help, agreed.
